# Android Memory Leak android.os.message usb scanner

Tags: android, memory-leaks, barcode-scanner, android-input-method

I run into a memory leak in android at an unexpected place.
There is a tablet and a hardware usb barcode scanner.The input from the scanner must be used to identify a product.So, I have extended an edittext and on its keyListener have intercepted the input when a usb barcode scanner input comes and from that input, I handle the rest of my use case.

The problem arises when I switch between fragments, the memory consumption increases and on deeper analysis using MAT this is what i get.

[image]

I am unable to trace this to any part in my code.

Edit: Upon further investigation I found that calling notifyDataSetChanged() of the listview adapter with the usb scanner connected, is the root cause of this issue.

Any hacks to handle this?